# how to use <a href ></a> in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

i have three columns column(0),column(1),column(2)and i want   tag for these three columns  in following code  for this line: "strNewContents = strNewContents & "" & columns(0) & "" & columns(1) & "" & columns(2) & "" & vbcrlf:"

actual code:

```
Dim strFileName1
Dim objFSO, objTextFile
Dim intLineNumber, strNewContents, strReadLineText,strLineNumbers
dim data, columns

strFileName1 = "saveimagename.txt"

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFileName1))

intLineNumber = 0
strLineNumbers = ""

data = split(objTextFile.readall(), vbcrlf)

for intLineNumber = 0 to ubound(data)
    columns = split(data(intLineNumber), ",", 3)
    if (ubound(columns) = 2) then
       ''//strNewContents =  "<td class='red'>" & columns(0) & "</td><td class='blue'>" & columns(2) & "</td>" 
       strNewContents = strNewContents & "<tr><td>" & columns(0) & "</td><td>" & columns(1) & "</td><td>" & columns(2) & "</td></tr>" & vbcrlf
    end if
next
```

Comment: That's the sloppiest code I've ever seen. Do you not use an IDE? Something that will automatically correct your capitalization errors?

Answer (score 5):

You are already using `Response.Write` with strings.

You simply:

`Response.Write "<a href=""" & link & """>" & linkName & "</a>"`